# Error when deleting a pointer that has been declared as new?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I am writing a program right now that alters a `C_String` using pointers to the string. I have an implementation that works fine. The only problem I am running into is that when I reach the end of my program, if I try to delete the pointers I get an error.

My code:

```
void CStringSwitcher()
{

    string input = "";
    char* cStringArray = new char[ASIZE];
    char* reversed = new char[ASIZE];
    const char* originalReversed = reversed;
    char* pointers[POINTER_SIZE];
    memset(reversed, '\0', ASIZE);
    memset(cStringArray, '\0', ASIZE);
    memset(pointers, '\0', POINTER_SIZE);
    char* current = cStringArray;
    cout << "Enter a sentence on each line. Input a 0 to stop." << endl;

    // Receives input from the user and stores it into cStringArray
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << ">";
        cin.clear();
        fflush(stdin);
        input = "";
        getline(cin, input);
        if (input == "0")
            break;
        else
        {
            input.append("\n");
            pointers[i] = current;
            _CRT_SECURE_STRCPY(pointers[i], ASIZE - 1, input.c_str());
            current += input.length();
            i++;
        }
    } while(i < POINTER_SIZE);
    char* end = current;

    --i;
    do
    {
        /// Check if done
        if(i < 0)
            break;
        /// Copy from current to end
        current = pointers[i];
        do
        {

            *reversed++ = *current++;
        }while(current < end);
        /// Update end
        end = pointers[i];
        /// Update i
        --i;
    }while(true);
    *reversed = '\0';
    cout << endl << originalReversed << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    //delete[] originalReversed;
    //delete[] cStringArray;
    return;
}
```

As it is written above the code works fine, however if I uncomment the two delete lines just before the return I was getting an error:

> Project_06.exe has initiated a breakpoint

and the program crashes. Weird thing is I just ran the program again to get the exact wording of the error message and it runs with no error? Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: Memory corruption.  Apply `valgrind`.

Comment: Is POINTER_SIZE > ASIZE?

Comment: the problem is that you got too many stars in your source code for it to works fine. reduce number of stars, and the program will magically work again

Comment: @Zack his code looks like he develops for windows. valgrind is linux only

Comment: Except in the use of `std::cout` this has nothing to do with C++, is C

Comment: I don't know what your crash is, but I do know that `memset(pointers, 0, POINTER_SIZE)` doesn't do quite what you think.  If anything, you want `memset(pointers, 0, sizeof(char *) * POINTER_SIZE)`.  The name `POINTER_SIZE` is also a little misleading...

Comment: While the logic is a wee bit convoluted, I don't see an obvious error.  I do wonder if the _total_ length of the input is larger than ASIZE, or if the number of lines read in is greater than POINTER_SIZE.  I don't know anything about `_CRT_SECURE_STRCPY`.  Is it guaranteed to NUL-terminate strings?  Whether or not it is, you should limit it to copying in `ASIZE - total_length_so_far - 1` characters (where `total_length_so_far` would represent the total number of characters you've put in the string array so far.)

Comment: @BЈовић Then he or she should switch to Linux. No, I am not joking.  `valgrind` is so valuable that its non-availability on some OS *by itself* disqualifies that OS as a C development platform, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Better not to write code that will routinely require you to use Valgrind in the first place, and I've found using Visual Studio a massive boon to writing good code in the first place, even though my code primarily targets Linux/BSD and the performance requirements are far from trivial. The only valgrind tools I've needed to use have been cachegrind/callgrind the past few years.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this code is an educational/practice piece to try and solidify your knowledge of pointers, but to be frank with you: it's an absolute horror to read.

This answer is in the spirit of "teach a man to fish".

Start by removing all of the allocations and instead use fixed-sized arrays.

```
char cStringArray[ASIZE] = "";
char reversed[ASIZE] = "";
```

This eliminates the need for the memsets for now, this assignment actually sets the entire array to 0s (see http://ideone.com/WmLtQp).

Doing it this way makes it much easier to catch corruption while running it thru the debugger.

Then switch the arrays over to dynamic allocations.

Lastly, don't mix stdin and cin, doing so can invoke undefined behavior.

---- Edit ----

Here is a C++-refactoring of your code. This particular piece shows both how to do it by hand (manually copying the bytes) and using C++ features to reduce the amount of work we have to do ourselves.

ideone live demo: http://ideone.com/0KuGiB

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void CStringSwitcher()
{
    std::vector<std::string> inputs;
    size_t totalLength = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter a sentence on each line. Input a 0 to stop." << std::endl;
    inputs.reserve(16);

    for ( ; /* until break */ ; ) {
        std::cout << ">";
        std::string input;
        getline(std::cin, input);
        if (input == "0")
            break;
        inputs.push_back(input);
        totalLength += input.length() + 1; // for the '\n'
    }

    std::string reversed = "";
    reversed.reserve(totalLength); // eliminate allocations

    // walk backwards thru the list of strings.
    for (auto inputsIt = inputs.rbegin(); inputsIt != inputs.rend(); ++inputsIt) {
        const std::string& input = *(inputsIt);

#ifndef REAL_CODE
        // educational, Do-It-Yourself way
        const size_t length = input.length();

        // walk backwards thru the characters
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            reversed += input[length - 1 - i];
        }
#else
        // call append with reversed iterators to do it for us.
        reversed.append(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
#endif

        // add the trailing '\n'
        reversed += '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << reversed << std::endl;

    // don't pause, set a break point at the end of the function
    // or run without debugging.

    return;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    CStringSwitcher();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: added a next-step example of doing it in C++ rather than using C functions throughout

Answer (score 0):

```
_CRT_SECURE_STRCPY(pointers[i], ASIZE - 1, input.c_str());
current += input.length();

ASIZE-=input.length();
```

**ASIZE-=input.length();**

Don't know why it helps to get rid of error. This should only prevent from overflow if size of new string > size of the remaining bytes. Looks like some Microsoft-Specific magic.

Also there are many errors in you code, but this is another story. Just consider using vector, unique_ptr.

---EDIT---

**I came with some weird things.**

_CRT_SECURE_STRCPY is define to strcpy_s

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char arr[10];
    iota(arr, end(arr), 'A');
    for (auto i : arr) cout << i << '\t'; cout << '\n';

    strcpy_s(arr, "");

    for (auto i : arr) cout << i << '\t'; cout << '\n';
}
```

My output is:

A B C D E F G H I J

(nonpritable characters)

It means that strcpy_s rewrites WHOLE destination buffer. Even if you pass one char.